# Homotopy classes of maps from the projective plane to $S^1 \times S^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have a past qual question here: characterize the space $[(\mathbb{RP}^2,x),(S^1 \times S^3,y)]$ of homotopy classes of maps from $(\mathbb{RP}^2,x)$ to $(S^1 \times S^3,y)$, where here $x \in \mathbb{RP}^2$ and $y \in S^1 \times S^3$ are base points.

In cases where we are considering homotopy classes of maps into $S^1$, I've used the relation $[X,S^1] = H^1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ when $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. Is there a similar relation in this case? If so, does it have to do with changing coefficients?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What can you say about a cellular map $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to S^3$?

Comment: Would the 2-cell and the 1-cell of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ both be sent to the 0-cell of $S^3$, since $S^3$ would only have a 0-cell and a 3-cell? So it would be the zero map?

Comment: Try to prove that every such map is null-homotopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By cellular approximation, the image of any map $\Bbb RP^2 \to S^1 \times S^3$ lies in a copy of $S^1$ inside $S^1 \times S^3$. Now use covering spaces to show that any map $\Bbb RP^2 \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood, we then conclude that $[\mathbb{RP}^2, S^1 \times S^3]$ consists of (the equivalence class of) a single constant map. Is that correct?

Comment: @msteve Yes. All such maps are nullhomotopic.